# How do you calculate whether a number is a decimal or a whole number in a SharePoint calculated field?

Tags: sharepoint, formulas

I'm trying to calculate whether a number is a whole number or a decimal in a SharePoint calculated field so that i can determine whether the item is published or not. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I had this but it isn't working:

=IF(MOD(Version,1),"Draft","Published")

Comment: Are you sure `Version` is stored as a number and not a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(CEILING(Version,1)-Version>0, "Draft", "Published")
```

The [`CEILING(number,significance)` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ceiling-function-HP010342225.aspx) returns number rounded up, away from zero, to the nearest multiple of significance.

Example:

- Draft - `CEILING(1.5,1) - 1.5 = 2 - 1.5 = 0.5`
- Published - `CEILING(3.0,1) - 3.0 = 3 - 3 = 0`